# rmi over ssl/tls, any way to securely identify the caller?

Tags: java, certificate, rmi, ssl

is there any way to securely get the method invoker while running the called method (server-side)?

i know there's a client string reachable through the server properties, but isn't it too "weak"? any way to get e.g. the client certificate owner?

please give me a couple of hints, WILL RTFD right afterwards ;)

thanks in advance

Comment: Pity about this: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/results?id=325

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't thought this through too thoroughly, but off-hand, I'd suggest a plugging in a custom [`TrustManager`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/TrustManager.html) that, after authenticating the caller, associates the client certificate with the caller's thread. This could be done simply with a `ThreadLocal`, or using the JAAS architecture.

Comment: thanks a lot;
i will investigate it. 
any other suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the *major* problems with RMI/SSL. There is no way to obtain the peer certificate other than via extra code such as erickson's suggestion. That actually makes it insecure, as there is no way of performing an authorization step: you get privacy, integrity, and authentication, but no authorization. See my [White Paper](http://www.telekinesis.com.au/wipv3_6/SocketFactoriesConsideredHarmful.A21) for an extended discussion.